# K(G,1) space is unique up to homotopy equivalence

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes, eilenberg-maclane-spaces

I am reading Hatcher's Proposition 1B.9 page 90. He is trying to prove that if $X$ is a connected CW complex, $Y$ is $K(G,1)$ then every homomorphism $\pi_1(X,x_0) \rightarrow \pi_1(Y,y_0)$ is induced by a map $(X,x_0) \rightarrow (Y,y_0)$. Specifically, I fail to see why in order to extend $f$ over a cell $e^2_\beta$ with attaching map $\omega_\beta: S^1 \rightarrow X^1$, we need $f\omega_\beta$ to be nullhomotopic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that we're given a map $g: S^1 \rightarrow X$ and we want to know when it extends to a map $D^2 \rightarrow X$. This happens precisely when $g$ is nullhomotopic.

If $g$ is nullhomotopic then there is a homotopy $H:S^1 \times I \rightarrow X$ so that $H(-,0) = g$ and $H(-,1)$ is a constant map. This means that $H$ descends to a map $H':(S^1 \times I)/(S^1 \times \{1 \}) \rightarrow X$ and since $(S^1 \times I)/(S^1 \times \{1 \}) \approx D^2$ we're done. The proof is easily reversible as well so we see that $g$ extends to a map $D^2 \rightarrow X$ iff $g$ is nullhomotopic.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: That makes sense. And this argument would generalize to higher dimensional sphere as well?

Comment: That's right! @CuriousAlpaca